# Concurrent reads and writes to a file descriptor

Tags: c++, multithreading, select, thread-safety, uart

I am trying to do concurrent reads and writes in a C++ program to a file descriptor that connects to a UART device.  What I am doing is similar to the following pseudocode

```
fd = get_fd();
make_non_blocking(fd);

while (1) {
    check_to_see_if_there_are_writes_pending_and_do_them();

    read_all_available_data_and_signal_waiting_threads();
}
```

The way a thread writes to this file descriptor is by writing its data block to a queue and then the `check_to_see_if_there_are_writes_pending_and_do_them()` function polls that queue and makes the writes.  But as you guys can probably notice, there is busy waiting here.  Is there a way that I can somehow make maybe a `select()` or `poll()` call that releases a mutex and then sleeps until there is data and then as soon as there is data it acquires the mutex again and then reads from the file descriptor?  I can just add the `select()` call before the `read_all_available_data_and_signal_waiting_threads()` function call but I do not know whether calling `select()` or `poll()` on a file descriptor that is being written to will cause problems.  I am talking about code like the following

```
fd = get_fd();
make_non_blocking(fd);

while (1) {
    check_to_see_if_there_are_writes_pending_and_do_them();

    release_mutex_so_writer_threads_can_access();
    select(fd);
    acquire_mutex();
    read(fd);
}
```

Could someone please show me an acceptable way to achieve this?  Or whether the above method is fine and the OS (a Mac OSx version 10.11.3) takes care of the multiplexing and the thread safety for me?

Thanks!

*NOTE* : I read a question that seems to be related to this question elsewhere on Stack Overflow but I do not believe that I have the same problem here.  If I am wrong please link me to it and I will delete this question!

**NOTE** : I am currently using condition variables to build the thread safe write queue.  I wanted to ask whether it would be okay to interleave a `select()` or `poll()` call with a `write()` to the same fd.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you don't try to read and write to a fliediscriptor concurrently. It is "just" about inter-thread synchronization - correct?

Comment: Yes! that is what I am trying to accomplish!

Comment: If all you want to know is *"is it okay to write to a file descriptor while someone has called select() on it?"* (I believe the answer is yes) then I'd really suggest, you strip your question down to just that. Or leave something like a [mcve](/help/mcve) that at least shows the different threads and how they are supposed to interact.